# node:events:492 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, node-modules, nodes

i tired to install a bot get from github but dont work i dont know where is problem  please check the error and help me

https://github.com/lefdilia/Axabot

NOTE: im new to nodejs

--My pc terminal--

```
PS C:\Users\LoorD\Axabot\_init> npm install
                                
up to date, audited 112 packages in 3s
8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 vulnerabilities (3 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\LoorD\Axabot\_init> npm start

> botinit@1.0.0 start
> node _install.js


[1] New Server Install ( To setup newly bought servers )
[2] Bot Only (Fresh install of Axabot [FILES ONLY])
[0] CANCEL

Please choose install type? [1, 2, 0]: 1
* Ip Address : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
* Username : root
* Password : ********
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\tmp\rsync_pass'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\tmp\\rsync_pass'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
PS C:\Users\LoorD\Axabot\_init>
```

--My Server terminal--

```
qweasd@Axabot:~$ suPassword:root@Axabot:/home/qweasd#
apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists... DoneBuilding dependency tree... DoneReading state information... Donersync is already the newest version (3.2.7-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.root@Axabot:/home/qweasd#
```

I did as tutorial except used Debian 12 64 bits then Debian 9 64 bits as say tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are encountering an "ENOENT" (Error NO ENTry) error in your Node.js application.
This error occurs when the program tries to access a file or directory that does not exist.
In your case, the file 'C:\tmp\rsync_pass' is not found.

Verify if the file 'C:\tmp\rsync_pass' actually exists at the specified location.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = 'C:\\tmp\\rsync_pass';

try {
    // Check if the file exists
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        // Proceed with file operations
        console.log(`File found: ${filePath}`);
    } else {
        throw new Error(`File not found: ${filePath}`);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
}
```

Check this code.
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an issue during the installation process via SSH :

1. Confirm correct IP, username, and password.
2. Check user permissions for file uploads.

Look for specific error messages for more details.